# PHP CLI Add value to $_SERVER

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I know I can add a custom value to the $_SERVER variable through Nginx with

```
fastcgi_param MY_VARIABLE "myValue";
```

Is it possible to add the same variable to PHP CLI $_SERVER? This would be used specifically for cron jobs. I'm using an Ubuntu server.

One option I've found is to call the PHP script like

```
$ MY_VARIABLE="myValue" php /path/to/php/script
```

But this seems less than ideal.

By default environmental variables are not sent to PHP and as I understand it, doing so will slow things down slightly. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to put the variable into /etc/environment. The settings in this are loaded by cron jobs and CLI and show in PHP $_SERVER.

By default /etc/environment has one line for PATH. Simply add a new line at the end of the file.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin: ... "
MY_VARIABLE="myValue"
```

As a side note, the PATH setting is this file seems to be overwritten by PHP as shown in $_SERVER.

PHP web service does not show the variable but adding it to the Nginx configuration is easy enough.

Comment: This has worked for me several times on private environments where I have write access to `/etc/environment` but I'm looking for a way to pass this variables to the CLI on a shared hosting environment where I'm not able to change the contents of `/etc/environment` . Do you know any way to do this? I really want to keep those vars outside of version control

Comment: The only ways I know are to set system wide in `/etc/environment`, in web server config (Apache or Nginx) or on the command line by declaring the variable before the script call. This is probably why loading `.env` or `.ini` files is so prevalent.